# How to propagate my VLOOKUP Excel command to multiple rows?

Tags: excel, vlookup

My VLOOKUP command is like this for column-D, row-3 in Sheet1:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!C3, ABBREV!B2:BA8791, 2, FALSE)
```

I search for 'Sheet1!C3' in the first column of 'ABBREV!B2:BA8791', and if there is exact match I return with a value in column '2'.

Above works for the selected cell D3.  But how to propagate this to more cells below it (~10000) quickly changing the formula only at C3? i.e. For D4 I only need C3 changed to C4 in the above formula.  Dragging the corner of the cell doesn't work. Selecting all the cells I want to populate and entering ctrl+Enter changes the range in C3 as well as the ranges in ABBREV in the formula.  Using ctrl+Shft+Enter doesn't change C3 to C4.

Answer (score 0):

as pnuts said, you should use static address for your source table, change your code to

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!C3, ABBREV!$B$2:$BA$8791, 2, FALSE)
```

when Excel copy formula, it will change addresses to make best representation to your needs, but changing the source table that you are looking into it will make error in some earlier lookups that you have change ABBREV!B2:BA8791 to ABBREV!$B$2:$BA$8791.

using `ABBREV!B:BA` not suggested as we don't know that in `ABBREV` sheet, you have just one table or more, and it can cause wrong results.

using $ before each ROWs or COLUMNs tells excel to don't change this ROW or COLUMN automatically. for example you can use $C3 in your code to tell excel to change `3` if row changes, but don't change `C` if column changes. of curse this is not necessary right now, and I used it as an example.